Multivariate Chain Rule with Derivatives in Intermediate Functions
I have a function
$$G: \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$$
where $d$ is a positive integer and the arguments of $G$ are denoted by $({\bf y}, z, {\bf p})$. I'm denoting partial derivatives of $G$ by $G_{y_1}, \ldots, G_{y_d}, G_z, G_{p_1},\ldots,G_{p_d}$, and I'll use $G_{\bf y}$ and $G_{\bf p}$ to denote $d$-dimensional vectors of partial derivatives. The arguments are parametrised as
\begin{align*}
    {\bf y} &= {\bf x}, \\
    z &= f_t({\bf x}), \\
    {\bf p} &= \nabla_{\bf x}f_t({\bf x})
\end{align*}
where $f: \mathbb R^d \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R, f({\bf x},t)=f_t({\bf x})$ is some function whose arguments $({\bf x}, t)$ can be thought of as spatial and temporal variables. I have applied the multivariate chain rule for each $1\leq i\leq d$ as follows
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} G({\bf x}, f({\bf x}), \nabla_{\bf x}f({\bf x}))
    &= G_{y_i}({\bf x}, f({\bf x}), \nabla_{\bf x}f({\bf x})) \\
    &\quad+ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f_t({\bf x}) \cdot G_z({\bf x}, f({\bf x}), \nabla_{\bf x}f({\bf x})) \\
    &\quad+ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \nabla_{\bf x} f_t({\bf x}) \cdot G_{\bf p}({\bf x}, f({\bf x}), \nabla_{\bf x}f({\bf x})),
\end{align*}
where the third term contains a dot product (the second term is scalar multiplication).
Am I correct in saying that the partial derivative on the left hand side is equal to the first term on the right simply because ${\bf x} = {\bf y}$? And if so, can I then equate the second and third terms for all $1\leq i\leq d$ as
\begin{align*}
    \nabla_{\bf x} f_t({\bf x}) \cdot G_z({\bf x}, f({\bf x}), \nabla_{\bf x}f({\bf x}))
    &= -H(f_t({\bf x})) G_{\bf p}({\bf x}, f({\bf x}), \nabla_{\bf x}f({\bf x})),
\end{align*}
where $H(f_t({\bf x}))$ is the Hessian matrix of second order partial derivatives?
It's not clear to me intuitively why this should work or what it means, so any intuition on this setup would be a bonus. For context, the textbook I'm working on is Gradient Flows In Metric Spaces and in the Space of Probability Measures by Ambrosio et al., [Section 10.4.1].

You actually did the total derivative $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx_i}$ of $G$, so no, you cannot cancel the first term.
